# document.getElementById("").value returns object instead value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

I have an data in below given format

```
{
 USA: { 
    CA: { 'SAN FRANCISCO':['94188', '94158', '94143'] },
    LA: { 'BATON ROUGE':['70898','70895','70891'] }
  }
}
```

trying to add them to dependent drop downs namely Country, State, City and Zip code. I'm using ng-option but while getting the value for country dropdown its returning oject:16 instead of value.

```
$scope.countries = {
    USA: { 
       CA: { 'SAN FRANCISCO':['94188', '94158', '94143'] },
       LA: { 'BATON ROUGE':['70898','70895','70891'] }
    }
}

$scope.GetSelectedCountry = function () {
    $scope.strCountry = document.getElementById("country").value;
}
```

```
<b>Country:</b>
&nbsp;
<select id="country" ng-model="statessource" ng-disabled="!type" ng-options="country for (country, states) in countries" ng-change="GetSelectedCountry()">
<option value=''>Select Country</option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used an ng-model variable for your select tag, but you have not used that in your controller to get the selected value. There is no need to access the value using javascript dom selector, instead you can directly use the model value of the select tag `$scope.statessource`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.countries = {
                USA: {
                    CA: {
                        'SAN FRANCISCO': ['94188', '94158', '94143']
                    },
                    LA: {
                        'BATON ROUGE': ['70898', '70895', '70891']
                    }
                }
            }

            $scope.GetSelectedCountry = function () {
                $scope.strCountry = $scope.statessource;
                console.log($scope.strCountry);
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <b>Country:</b> &nbsp;
    <select id="country" ng-model="statessource" ng-options="country for (country, states) in countries" ng-change="GetSelectedCountry()">
        <option value=''>Select Country</option>
    </select>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not the *Angular way* to get values.

You use `<select ng-model="statessource" ...>`, so the value of the select is stored in `$scope.statessource`.

This should works:

```
$scope.GetSelectedCountry = function() {
    $scope.strCountry = $scope.statessource;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your only concern is to get the currently selected value each and every time a user changes it, your `ng-model` will already handle this case.
So, by using this

```
<select id="country" ng-model="statessource" ng-disabled="!type" ng-options="country for (country, states) in countries">
```

Angular would always apply its two-way-data-binding to store the currently selected option inside your `$scope.statessource`-variable.

Other than that, if you want to do other stuff related to a change of the selection, you can do the following:

```
<select id="country" ng-model="statessource" ng-disabled="!type" ng-options="country for (country, states) in countries" ng-change="GetSelectedCountry(statessource)">

$scope.GetSelectedCountry = function (newState) {
  // Do something with your newState variable.
  // Remember, $scope.statessource still includes the currently selected
  // option
}
```

I hope that helped :)

Answer (score -2):

The way to access the selected value of an `OPTION` nested in a `SELECT` is here:

```
var e = document.getElementById("country");
var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

Comment: This is not the angularjs way